# How to transform queried data to an array FaunaDB typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, facebook-fql, faunadb

I could display the result of my pagination query (FaunaDB,FQL) in the console and it appears as a javascript object. Yet, I cannot access the properties of said object and even less can I convert it to an array using the spread operator. How could I do that?

I am aware there exists a pagination helper but could not make it work, as explained above. Here is the latest code I am trying:

```
var array=[]
qu(q.Map(
    q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index('FeesByIndex'))),
    q.Lambda(x => q.Get(x))
   )).then(res => { console.log(res); array=[...res] })//the log really looks like a js object and res is said to be one
```

It says type object is not an array type. Also, property data is said not to exist on res, although it clearly does in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to specify the index term and the Lambda has syntax errors.

The response object has a data property, which is a list.

In my repositories I use this snippet if the query returns multiple object:

```
    const result: Fee[] = [];

    await CLIENT.query(
      q.Map(
        q.Paginate(
          q.Match(
            q.Index('FeesByIndex'),
            'index term',
          ),
        ),
        q.Lambda('fees', q.Get(q.Var('fees'))),
      )
    )
    .then(faunaResponse => {
      const dataArray = faunaResponse.data;
      dataArray.forEach(s => {
        const data = s.data;
        result.push({
          id: data.id,
          yourProp1: data.yourProp1,
          yourProp2: data.yourProp2,
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(e => logger.error(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

would you try this way?

```
var array=[]
  qu(q.Select(['data'],
      q.Map(
          q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index('FeesByIndex'))),
          q.Lambda(x => q.Get(x))
      )
    )
  ).then(res => { console.log(res); array=[...res] })
```